# I downloaded a webfont but it only works in brackets

Tags: css, fonts, adobe-brackets

So I downloaded a font (legally I bought it)
and the font looks really good. but it only displays in the brackets live preview.
when I open it in chrome, it just refuses to work. I followed all the instructions on the font when I bought it. Can anyone help me?

This is an image of the bracket font display which is what I want:
[image: this is an image of the bracket font display which is what I want]

And this is the exact same code when I open the `index.html` file in Google Chrome.
[image: and this is the exact same code when I open the index.html file in Google Chrome.]

This is the code I am using to get the font in CSS

```css
@font-face{
   font-family:"Ethnocentric W05 Italic";
   src:url("/fonts/MTI-WebFonts-367222846/Fonts/5118942/e91f32ff-44ec-47c0-afd3-5cdeeb6c73c8.woff2") 
   format("woff2");
}
```

and this is what I used to put it in the header

```css
font-family: "Ethnocentric W05 Italic";
```

Comment: Have you looked at the console on your browsers dev tools to make sure that the font is loading OK?

Comment: Yes I have, everything seems fine like it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare a custom font using @font-face, the browser will try to fake the bold and italic styles if it can’t find them.

Instead of defining separate font-family values for each font, You can use same font-family name for each font, and define the matching styles, like so:

```
[css]@font-face {
font-family: 'Ubuntu';
src: url('Ubuntu-R-webfont.eot');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
font-family: 'Ubuntu';
src: url('Ubuntu-I-webfont.eot');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
font-family: 'Ubuntu';
src: url('Ubuntu-B-webfont.eot');
font-weight: bold;
font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
font-family: 'Ubuntu';
src: url('Ubuntu-BI-webfont.eot');
font-weight: bold;
font-style: italic;
}

.test {
font-family: Ubuntu, arial, sans-serif;
}[/css]
```

Then all you need to do is apply that single font-family to your target, and any nested bold or italic styles will automatically use the correct font, and still apply bold and italic styles if your custom font fails to load.